# Showing divergence of the integral of a periodic function

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, solution-verification

> Let $f: [1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continous periodic function, none negative, which is **not the zero function**. Show that the integral $\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ diverges.

---

This is my solution but I am not sure if it is true, I feel there are some details I miss.

We know that $f$ is not the zero function, let $I=[a,b]$ be the periodic part of the function, so we know that we have for sure $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq I$ that $f(x)>0$ for every $x\in [x_1,x_2]$. Thus, there exist $M>0$ s.t $M\leq f(x)$ Hence we can say that $\frac{M}{x}\leq \frac{f(x)}{x}$ for $x\in [x_1,x_2]$.

From here I applied the Convergence tests with the divergence integral $\frac{1}{x}$ and I showed the limit is $M$ which is a finite number.
I feel this is not good enough, or should I say not a professional proof?

I would like appreciate for notes and reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is continuous with period $t>0$. Then
$$A:=\int_1^{1+t}f(x)\text{d}x>0.$$
Fix $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ and we have
\begin{align*}
I_n& =\int_1^{1+nt}\frac{f(x)}{x}\text{d}x=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{1+(k-1)t}^{1+kt}\frac{f(x)}{x}\text{d}x\\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n\int_1^{1+t}\frac{f(x)}{x+(k-1)t}\text{d}x>\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{A}{1+kt}.
\end{align*}
Thus $I_n\to +\infty,n\to \infty$. The original integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\text{d}x$ diverges.

Comment: Can you please explain the line : $\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{1+(k-1)t}^{1+kt}\frac{f(x)}{x}\text{d}x\
 =\sum_{k=1}^n\int_1^{1+t}\frac{f(x)}{x+(k-1)t}\text{d}x$, 
how did the limits of k removed from the integral limits and became part of the fraction?

Comment: @Sagigever Substituting $y=x+(k-1)t$ can obtain $f(x)=f(y-(k-1)t)=f(y)$ from the period $t$. In addition, $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{A}{1+kt}>\frac{A}{1+t}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\to +\infty$.